# How has this old question not been closed already?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Take a look at this very old question that I came across in the review queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90446/learning-php-for-fun-and-profit

Can you imagine the response this would get if it were asked today? Wouldn't this qualify as "not constructive"? How has it remained open for years?

**UPDATE:**

The above question is now closed.

Comment: I'm not sure why I got a down vote.

Comment: I suspect you got a downvote for not simply voting to close, which with 3k rep you can do. As it's so old you could also flag for moderator attention with the "other" reason and explain why you have done so. There's no real need to bring each one up on meta; there's (tens of) thousands of not constructive questions out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the reason the question was open for so long was because it was posted *way* back when Stack Overflow was still trying to figure itself out.  In its current state it wouldn't survive today, but I think that closing it is kind of a moot point, despite it being closed now.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno, but it's attracted three close votes already, and I suspect it may be closed by the time I press "Post Your Answer".